# What equipment/ Which settings required for a 400 person group photo?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-settings, group-photos

I received a request to work at a corporate party with a special request 
for a group photo of +- 400 people. So far the largest I've had was
aprox. 35 people. I work with a Canon Eos 550 and a 35mm or 18-200mm lens.

I would be a shot at the beginning of March between
17:00-18:00 in the Netherlands (meaning relatively little light & prob no direct
sunlight). What approach would you recommend?

Thank you for your time,

Simone

Comment: Does [How to take photos of large groups (over 100 people)?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19781/how-to-take-photos-of-large-groups-over-100-people) help?